# Scrollable Table with Fixed Header using jQuery custom content scroller

Tags: jquery, html, scrollbar

Please help me to get Scrollable Table with Fixed Header jQuery custom content scroller (here is plugin home page http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller )

i have next table:

```
<table>
   <thead>            
       <tr>
              <th>First</th>
              <th>Second></th>
              <th>Third</th>
        </tr>
   </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
                       ....
              <td>n</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
                      ....            
              <td>n</td>
            </tr>
                      ....  
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

i need to fix thead on top

it should be something like this demo http://salzerdesign.com/test/fixedTable.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead using [this](http://laertejjunior.github.io/freezeheader/) jQuery plugin for fixed table headers. It's pretty well supported and he even shows code snippets of how to implement it.

It makes it as easy as adding a line of jQuery to your `.js` file.

```
        $("#tableid").freezeHeader(offset : '50px');
```

You would just need to make each table have a unique `id` and plug that inplace of the `#tableid`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not very experienced programmer, please tell me what exactly I need to do

Comment: If you're looking for a developer to do your job for you then this isn't the place.